# PTIJ: Which Talmudic disputes would make for good political attack ads?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Inspired by the [attack ad to vote against "Humpty Dumpty: *Wrong on Wall-Sitting*."](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nV-OBRVrGuw)

What would be a good (bad?) attack ad if an issue of Talmudic debate was up to the electorate? Rabbi Eliezer's oven had *I'm G-d and I support this message* ... bonus points if you write convincing copy for both sides of the debate.

(Hopefully this will be good material to perform at your Purim seudah or shpiel.)

They can be debates in Rishonim or Achronim too, and Brisker chakiros are totally fair game ... e.g. "is hiddur a chelek of the mitzva itself."

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).